# asp.net mvc another controller in the same folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a folder 'Report' which holds ReportController.

Now i want to add AgreementController to the same folder.

from javascript i have a code which runs 'Download' action (downloads file).

When i run from javascript - Report/Download/id='5' everything fine.

When i run from javascript - Report/Agreement/Download/id='5' everything bad.

How can i run 'Download' action from Agreement controller ?
I dont want one folder-one controller structure.

I think only areas can help me there ?

Comment: try Agreement/Download/id='5

Comment: could you also check your Routing definitions and add an extra one if needed to override the default {controller}{method}{id}

Comment: Thanks guys. I do think about areas, because is very possible that i will need more reports in the future. So areas can fix my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

according to routing:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

your code is:

```
Report/Agreement/Download/id='5'
```

so in your case:

```
 Controller= Report
 action=  Agreement 
 Id= Download.
```

that's why you get an error

You need to remove Report from call end use this:

```
Agreement/Download/id='5'
```

Answer (score 0):

***If you are writing js in same view page and not in external js file,*** you can use mvc url.action in ajax call file method to call appropriate controller and action method as described below

**syantax:**
*url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethodName","ControllerName",new {Parameters})'*

In your case it would be something like this:

1. to invoke report controller's  download method

   url: '@Url.Action("Download","Report",new { id = "Value" })'
2. to invoke agreement controller's  download method

   url: '@Url.Action("Download","Agreement",new { id = "Value" })'

***If you are using external js file then it will be as below***

1. url: serverbaeurl + "/Report/Download?id=" +  "Value"
2. url: serverbaeurl + "/Agreement/Download?id=" +  "Value"

   (here serverbaseurl will be the domain of website)

(you will have to add other ajax options as needed)